# how to hide connectionString of a database connection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, constants, connection-string

I am using sqlite in my app. I am declaring my `sqliteConnection` as `constant`. But the problem is that the user of this class can change the `connectionString` property of this `sqliteConnection` object. How I can prevent that? I want the connection string of the connection to be set just once.

Comment: if its declared with `const` keyword, it will be readonly by default.

Comment: By "user" you mean another developer with access to the code, or something else? If its a const it can't be changed in the code anymore.

Comment: I am referring to any developer who will use my class.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee - why not create a read-only property ? only with getter and no setter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a read-only property...

```
private string connectionString = "my_string";
public string ConnectionString
{
    get { return connectionString; }
}
```

*Or* a `readonly` field. The value can be set only in the constructor or as a constant:

```
public readonly ConnectionString = "my_string";
```

*Or* a `const` field. The value can be set as a constant (value is static, i.e. there will only be one value for all instances):

```
public const ConnectionString = "my_string";
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do `readonly` and `const` on one field.